# I want to use NavigationView inside my App but I can't find the right dependecy to implement for androidX

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I tried different versions and worked only with 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' when I pressed Sync, but using this one I can't use the NavigationView.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. When you are _new_ to something, you should start by reading the documentation, examples and other resources available. Asking such a question here will most likely only bring you down- and close-votes as it is too broad and doesn't show that you have tried anything. As you are also _new_ to Stackoverflow, I suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and related help pages.

Comment: Hope the link helps you... https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in the Gradle and sync

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Use the Navigation Drawer Activity provided by android studio 

Right click on your main folder -> new -> activity -> navigation drawer activity

Answer (score 0):

Use the Navigation Drawer Activity provided by android studio

Right click on your main folder -> new -> activity -> navigation drawer activity